# SSDT(SQL Server Data Tools) Missing from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I've installed Visual Studio 2015, but the ssdt features are missing as you can see below

[image: Missing SSDT]

I checked the ssdt option at the setup, and the only thing i did was change the default installation directory from c:/ to d:/ (don't know if it changes anything). When i use the Typical installation, ssdt installs fine, but it installs VS at c:/, and i need it installed at "D:/" ...

Here is a screenshot of my VS Setup

[image: Visual Studio Setup]

How can i have SSDT features back?

---

**EDIT:** To solve my problem i did the fist part of the third step at [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/mt186501), which was:

```
Download the appropriate version of SSDTSetup.exe for your chosen language from the table below (use the “save” option in your browser, rather than “run”):
Portuguese (Brazil) http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619232&clcid=0x416
Chinese (PRC)   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619232&clcid=0x804
German  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619232&clcid=0x407
English (United States) http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619232&clcid=0x409
Spanish http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619232&clcid=0x40a
French  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619232&clcid=0x40c
Italian http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619232&clcid=0x410
Japanese    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619232&clcid=0x411
Korean  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619232&clcid=0x412
Russian http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619232&clcid=0x419
Chinese (Taiwan)    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=619232&clcid=0x404
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try installing SSDT for Visual Studio 2015 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/mt186501

Note that it mentions that it supports Visual Studio 2015 Express and I notice you have the Community edition, so hopefully Community edition is supported as well.

Comment: this link tells me to update, but there's no update available for VS. Note that SSDT is supported by community edition because i used it before, just now by certain reasons i had to reinstall at another location and SSDT is gone...

Comment: If you have a SQL Server 2012/2014 installer, try to use it and just select SSDT from the list of features to be installed.

Comment: Thanks, i actually did the third step (Set up an Administrative Install Point (optional)) and that solved my problem...

Answer (score 5):

Link provided allows downloading
SSDT_14.0.50730.0

It did not help me.

This link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/he-il/mt429383
You can download SSDT_14.0.51215.0
SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio **Preview** 2015

That solved the problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hip Hip Hooray for the Answer.  Boo to Microsoft for this being the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a download location :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Could you try repairing SSDT from the Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features
Right clicking Microsoft Sql Server Data Tools
Click repair

Comment: unfortunately there is no "Microsoft Sql Server Data Tools" at Programs and Features